# What's the meaning of the word "spitters" in The Chemical Worker's Song?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, lyrics

Amongst the different versions of this song (Known by various names including "The Chemical Worker's Song", "Process Man" and "The ICI Song") that are floating around, there seem to be two variations of the second verse.

> Well I've worked among the **spitters** and I've breathed the oily smoke

and

> Well I've worked among the **spinners** and I've breathed the oily smoke

What could be the meaning of the word spitters? Is it just a mangling of the lyrics, or is it an antiquated term for some kind of occupation or machinery?

I doubt it would mean "people who spit".

I have a feeling spitters might be propagated from a transcription error in the [Great Big Sea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edAxujKev1I) recording, in which it is **very** difficult to distinguish the sound as *n* or *t*, (they may even be singing "spitters"). But I was curious to know if it was a variation that had some other legitimate meaning.

[The original recording by Ron Angel with the word "spinners"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1rOAMxSLVE)

Comment: it could be interpreted to mean any machinery that spits out something. dirty oil maybe?

Comment: Hmm, just found a use of the word "spitter" to mean a component in a grinding machine http://www.rockhounds.com/rockshop/articles/recirculating_drip/ @sgroves that sounds plausible!

Comment: It could refer to workers who spit because they are breathing chemicals that irritate their throats.

Comment: The original is likely referring to polymer spinners, in regular use when the song was written. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_(polymers). The reference to spitters is almost certainly a transcription error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A small ambiguity of pronunciation set up a dual lyrical standard. Clearly the original song by Ron Angel used the word *spinners*, as confirmed by [colorantshistory.org](http://www.colorantshistory.org/ICISong.html:):

> *I've worked among the **spinners** I've breathed in the oil and smoke.
>
>   **emphasis** mine*

*The spinners* clearly referred to machinery operated by employees of *[British Nylon Spinners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Nylon_Spinners)* (BNS), and one of the alternate  titles refers to BNS's parent company ***ICI***:

> British Nylon Spinners (BNS) was a British company set up in 1940 by
>   ICI and Courtaulds to produce nylon yarn.

There was no variance in the lyrics until the cover published by *Great Big Sea* in the 1995 release of their *[UP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_(Great_Big_Sea_album))* album. That version contained an [ambiguous pronunciation at the 55 second mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edAxujKev1I&list=RDedAxujKev1I). Although some of Great Big Sea's live versions  moved back to the original *spinners*, the ambiguity circulated by their popular album impacted [subsequent covers](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=chemical%20worker%27s%20song%20lyrics) of the song. Some artists move back to the original *[spinners](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22well%20I%27ve%20worked%20among%20the%20spinners%22)*, while others proliferate *[spitters](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22well%20i%27ve%20worked%20among%20the%20spitters%22)*. The published lyrics seem to suggest that *spitters* has overcome *spinners*, and even karaoke [lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwwexohwT70) associated with Great Big Sea's version use *[spitters](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/greatbigsea/thechemicalworkerssongprocessman.html)*.

It is often true that ambiguity adds value to poetry and lyrics. Since the nylon *spinners* of the mid 1900s are outside the context of 21st century listeners, *spitters* offers a more appealing visual of machines, factories and disgusted factory workers spewing out pollution and poison.

Answer (score 2):

The original lyric was, spinners. There was a nylon plant at  Billingham ICI ( the plant that the song was originally written about) that produced nylon yarn. Ronnie always sang spinners when he sang his song, I should know because he was a very good friend of mine and I had the great misfortune to have to work at the plant. The song says it all